# Elastic serach record upsert with a complex _id field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have to upsert bulk records in elastic search index with _id being combination of more than one field from the message. Can I  do so. if that can be done then please give me a sample json for the same.
Regards

A sample _id field I  am looking for some thing like below

```
        {
            "_index": "kpi_aggr",
            "_type": "KPIBackChannel",
            "_id": "<<<combination of name , period_type>>>",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "name": "kpi-v1",
                "period_type": "w",
                "country": "AL",
                "pg_name": "DENTAL CARE",
                "panel_type": "retail",
                "number_of_records_with_proposal": 10000,
                "number_of_proposals": 80000,
                "overall_number_of_records": 2000,
                "@timestamp": 1442162810
            }
        }
```

Comment: Afaik there can only be one id field, so you would need to combine all values into one string, ideally in a way that you don't get accidental identities between different comples ids.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, you can specify your own Elasticsearch document ids during a call to the [Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/docs-index_.html):

```
PUT kpi_aggr/KPIBackChannel/kpi-v1,w
{
  "name": "kpi-v1",
  "period_type": "w",
  "country": "AL",
  "pg_name": "DENTAL CARE",
  "panel_type": "retail",
  "number_of_records_with_proposal": 10000,
  "number_of_proposals": 80000,
  "overall_number_of_records": 2000,
  "@timestamp": 1442162810
}
```

You can also do so during a [`_bulk` API call](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/docs-bulk.html):

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "kpi_aggr", "_type" : "KPIBackChannel", "_id" : "kpi-v1,w" } }
{"name":"kpi-v1","period_type":"w","country":"AL","pg_name":"DENTAL CARE","panel_type":"retail","number_of_records_with_proposal":10000,"number_of_proposals":80000,"overall_number_of_records":2000,"@timestamp":1442162810}
```

Notice that Elasticsearch will replace the document with the new version.

If you execute these two queries on an empty index, then querying by document id:

```
GET kpi_aggr/KPIBackChannel/kpi-v1,w
```

will give you the following:

```
{
  "_index": "kpi_aggr",
  "_type": "KPIBackChannel",
  "_id": "kpi-v1,w",
  "_version": 2,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "name": "kpi-v1",
    "period_type": "w",
    "country": "AL",
    "pg_name": "DENTAL CARE",
    "panel_type": "retail",
    "number_of_records_with_proposal": 10000,
    "number_of_proposals": 80000,
    "overall_number_of_records": 2000,
    "@timestamp": 1442162810
  }
}
```

Notice `"_version": 2`, which in our case indicates that a document has been indexed twice, hence performed an "upsert" (but in general is meant to be used for [Optimistic Concurrency Control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html)).

Hope that helps!